# How to control between Merged, Nested and Index Nested Loop in Execution Plan

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am interested to know basic preferences which will decide which join is cheaper. I can force join types by typing merge, loop, hash into the join statement but I would like to know if there is a way to fix indexes, datatypes in order to provide conditions for particular cheapest join.

Let's say query plan returns Nested Loop as a cheapest join with current conditions. Is there a way to do something with whatever in order to make Sort Merge Join cheapest. I know for example that if I delete indexes it will use hash join so my question actually is what to change in order to control between Merged, Nested and Index Nested loop?

Comment: Why bother? Trust the optimizer. (A consistent database design makes things better!)

Comment: Optimizer works with current conditions but it does not mean that it is the best.

Comment: If you don't like what the optimizer does, use hints.